# Will these 2 electromagnet produce a 40kg (400N) attractive force?

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

Dear all, theoretically according to the electromagnet datasheet, it can attract with 20kg force, does that mean if I have 2 of the same electromagnet and if I switch it to different polarity from each other, it will produce a 20kg + 20 kg force = 40kg attractive force. The reason I asked is because the attraction force is not necessary 20 kg if I use a different kind of metal to attach to the electromagnet and pulled it. So, the reason why I asked for 2 electromagnets is because electromagnet are made up of good magnetic material so it would maximize the potential of the 2 electromagnets (20 kg + 20kg) :)

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: 20 kg isn't a unit of force, it's a unit of mass. Do you mean 200(ish) N?

Comment: @Hearth, yes :)

Comment: @Hearth I'd think it's a marketing way of saying that this thing can hold 20kg weight. But it should state the material at the very least. Shape matters too

Comment: @EugeneSh., it can reach almost 16kg for one electromagnet when I attach it with a spannar and measured it using spring balance:)

Comment: So, I believe with 2 of the electreomagnets with similar shape and size can maximize their potential to lift 40 kg easily

Comment: The force specification always assumes the best case. This would be a thick flat piece of steel larger than the electromagnet.

Comment: You can simply attach two of the magnets in parallel, assuming the load have enough area for a full grip. To benefit from the maximum "strength" the load should be well balanced though.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would be 40kg or something more like 80kg. It is true it would be stronger than just one magnte.

Comment: While the magnet can **hold** 20 kg, it will not **pick** 20 kg or anything like that when there is an air-gap between the magnet and the object.